# How to unmodule in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a library that I'd like to use in my webpage.  It seems that this library is only available as a "module".  It also seems that the "module" type of script is like a cancer that spreads uncontrollably: In order to use a module, I have to have a module, so all of my code that wants to use this library needs to be refactored as a module, and all of the code that uses that code then needs to be moduled, etc.  This is super non-trivial, because modules force all manner of asynchronous logic into your code, etc, which means that I have to completely rewrite my website.

Is it possible to use a "module" library in a "nomodule" sort of way?

Comment: Use a bundler like webpack.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-use-javascript-modules-in-the-browser

Comment: [Dynamic imports](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) can be used both in scripts and modules.

Comment: @jnpdx this is backwards.  I don't want to make my js module-like.  I want to make someone else's module un-module-like.

Comment: The video specifically addresses how to import modules. So does the link in the comment below mine.

Comment: Use something like unpkg.com